# Recognize image is TEM or STEM image in DM script

Tags: dm-script

For an image the global information-global tag may include the image is TEM or STEM,

Could we use the script code let the script get the information?

I mean the script code could recognize the image is TEM or STEM image.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If the acquired images contain meta-data (tags), then certainly you can use these to differentiate between the type of acquisition. These tags will be found with each image, not in the global tag. The exact tags might depend a bit on your GMS version and microscope, but usually you will need to look at the tags in the "Microscope Info" subgroup.

Here, in particular the sub-tag "Imaging Mode" will either be `IMAGING` or `SCANNING` or `DIFFRACTION`. 
To get these tags (provided they are there), you just need

```
string modeStr
if ( !GetFrontImage().ImageGetTagGroup().TagGroupGetTagAsString("Microscope Info:Imaging Mode",modeStr) )
    Throw( "Tag not found" )
Result("\n Mode:"+modeStr)
```

Example of image tags of an acquired EFTEM image:
[image: Example tags]